# reference mistake

Tags: ambiguity, reference

> When democracy fails, the people's last weapon is civil disobedience. It means actions that disobey the authority of the state, for instance illegal demonstrations and refusing to pay taxes.*
>
> Increasingly, a university degree is essential. For those who have it, there is plenty of work.

These two sentences allegedly include reference mistake: they use the word "it" inappropriately. Could you please explain to me why it is not possible to use "it" there?

Comment: I do not consider any mistake. But according to a native speaker the mistake consists in wrong usage of "it". So in the case of the first sentence it shall be probably "This means actions"…

Comment: So let's wait what our native speakers have to say ^_^

Comment: This native speaker says the second example is *definitely* wrong (the *it* should be *one*), and the first is debatable. You *could* keep that first *it* there, but it's awkward, and will give anyone reading the sentence pause.

Comment: The second sentence "It means actions that disobey the authority of the state, for instance illegal demonstrations and refusing to pay taxes." is incomplete. What is the source? As for the first *It*, I would use *This* to directly point to the previous statement.

Comment: This is an impressively divisive question. I personally think the first one is bad and the second one is fine.

Comment: I think they're both sloppy but understandable, but both have a distinct "foreign" feel to me. In both cases I hear "it" as reference to something that hasn't been explicitly stated, like "university education" in the second sentence. Much better with `this` and `one`.

Answer (score 3):

Swan, in *Practical English Usage* (p585) has an explanation why it should be *this* and not *it* in the first example:

> ## 590 this/that and it
>
> #### things that have just been mentioned
>
> #### 2  more than one thing
>
> When more than one thing has been mentioned, *it* generally refers to
>   the main subject of discussion; *this* and *that* generally refer to a new
>   subject that has been introduced (often the last thing mentioned).
>   Compare:
>             — *We keep the ice-cream machine in the spare room. **It** is used mainly by
>   the children*. (The machine is used by the children.)
>                 *We keep the ice-cream machine in the spare room. **This** is used mainly
>   by the children.* (The spare room is used by the children.)
>             — *I was carrying the computer to my office when I dropped it on the
>   kitchen table. **It** was badly damaged.* (The computer was damaged.)
>                 *I was carrying the computer to my office when I dropped it on the
>   kitchen table. **This** was badly damaged.* (The table was damaged.)

So, on this basis a likely initial interpretation of *it* will be that it refers to the 'main subject of discussion' (or topic / theme) of the sentence, namely the failure of democracy. The pronoun *this* is used to ensure that listener will understand the antecedent to be *civil disobedience*.

As to the second sentence, the pronoun should be *one* and not *it*. As Quirk et al. in *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (p387) state in the section entitled *Substitute one*:

> *One* ... is used as a substitute for *a/an* + noun:
>
> I'm having a drink. Would you like *one* too?

Swan, in his section entitled *one: substitute word*, states:

> We often use *one* instead of repeating a singular countable noun:
>
> ...
>
> Can you lend me a pen? - Sorry, I haven't got *one*.

In the example, *degree* is a singular countable noun preceded by the indefinite article, hence the referent needs to be *one*, not *it*.

It is worth noting that *it* is the pronoun used when the antecedent is preceded by a definite, rather than indefinite article.

> Where's the pen I lent you. - Sorry, I haven't got *it*.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer.

The second sentence would imply that there is only one university degree, whose ownership is shared by several people. Since this is not the case and each person has their own degree it should be

> Increasingly, a university degree is essential. For those who have **one**, there is plenty of work.

Answer (score 1):

> When democracy fails, the people's last weapon is **civil disobedience**. **It** means actions that disobey the authority of the state, for instance illegal demonstrations and refusing to pay taxes.

By analyzing the second sentence and what it is defining, we can see that the **it** refers to **civil obedience**. Normally, *it* here would be interpreted as referring to the previous sentence or statement, although *this* would be preferred if this were the case. As such, the **it** is misused and instead of saying **it**, **civil disobedience** should be respecified: "Civil disobedience means..."

> Increasingly, a university degree is essential. For those who have it, there is plenty of work.

In this example, it is clear that the **it** refers to **a university degree**, and this usage would normally be fine, except for the wording of the second sentence: **those who** is in the plural, and not everyone is sharing a single university degree. This would mean that the pronoun should be *them*, except that it's referring to a singular antecedent. Instead, a word like *one* should be used in place of **it**.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the *Main Clause* of the first sentence becomes the *Subject Noun* of the second sentence.

> When democracy fails, the people's last weapon is civil disobedience.
>   It means actions that disobey the authority of the state, for instance
>   illegal demonstrations and refusing to pay taxes.

The **It** (singular third person pronoun) refers to the aforementioned **Civil Disobedience**. How do we know? Because when democracy fails, **it** is the people's last weapon. **Mean** is used in its literal verb sense: *intend to convey, indicate, or refer to (a particular thing or notion)*.

What is the *particular thing or notion* in this context? *Actions that disobey the authority of the state, for instance illegal demonstrations and refusing to pay taxes.*

A simple way to word "*It means*" is, "(*Civil Disobedience*) (*Stands For*) actions that..."

> Increasingly, a university degree is essential. For those who have it,
>   there is plenty of work.

The **It** (singular third person pronoun) refers to the aforementioned **university degree**. How do we know? Because **it** is increasingly essential.

For those who have **a university degree**, there is plenty of work.